# Singleton thread safe SAX parser instance

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, sax

I want to create a singleton instance of a SAX parser which is thread safe.

But I cannot use on demand idiom as SAX parser throws SAXException which cannot be handled if it is made a class variable. Here is the code I have written.

```
public class Parser {
    private static SAXParser parser;
    Parser() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    if (parser==null)
        parser=LazyHolder.factory.newSAXParser();
    }
    private static class LazyHolder {
        private static final SAXParserFactory factory=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        }
    public SAXParser getInstance() {
        return parser;
    }
}
```

Is there any better way of achieving it?

Comment: I don't understand how this is supposed to work. Do you want few threads use same SAXParser instance? And when one thread is using this instance the others can't, am I right?

Comment: No I want something like single SAXParser instance can be used by different threads simultaneously. Is it really possible?

Comment: New Instances of Parsers are a bit costly .Is there any efficient way of reusing same instances in multiple threads. I am having problem in understanding it.

Comment: SAXParser is not thread safe, that is why different threads can't use same instance simultaneously. You could reuse one instance by few threads but one-by-one not simultaneously. If you expect concurrent parsing by different threads you have to create SAXParser instances pool.

Comment: We can also create new instance per thread.That will also work right?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption that SAXParser is thred safe is wrong. see the link below.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html

Earlier I was also in impression that SAXParser is thread safe, and sometimes I used to get following error, This was happening when one thread is already using parser object to parse the xml, and same time other thread also tried to use same object. The exception got fixed when I created SAXParser instance for each thread.

`org.xml.sax.SAXException: FWK005 parse may not be called while parsing.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1253) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195) ~[na:1.8.0_20]`

Answer (score 1):

> But I cannot use on demand idiom as SAX parser throws SAXException which cannot be handled if it is made a class variable.

If this is just about getting around the exception during initialization, you can get around this by doing something like the following:

```
 public class Wrapper {
     private static MyClassThatThrows singleton;
     static {
         try {
             singleton = new MyClassThatThrows();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
         }
     }
     ...
     public static MyClassThatThrows getInstance() {
        return singleton;
     }
}
```

This *will* stop the class from being loaded if the parser throws of course.

However, both the `SAXParserFactory` and the `SAXParser` are not thread-safe, so you could instead use a `ThreadLocal` instead to generate one per thread.

```
public class Parser {
    private final ThreadLocal<SAXParserFactory> factoryThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>() {
         public SAXParserFactory initialValue() {
             try {
                 return SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 throw new RuntimeException(e);
             }
         }
    };
    public SAXParser getInstance() {
        // you could catch and re-throw the RuntimeException if the caller should handle it
        return factoryThreadLocal.get().newInstance();
    }
}
```